Build time property cannot be changed at runtime in quarkus
I am updating quarkus.elasticsearch.health.enabled = false and getting this warning
"Build time property cannot be changed at runtime:\n - quarkus.elasticsearch.health.enabled was 'true' at build time and is now 'false'"
Is there any way to override the value?

I suppose changing the value is not possible.

You can only change it at build time, not runtime

Yes have changed it on buid time and it worked.
